# .NET Core 5 dependencies not included in Release compile

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm migrating a muti-project **.NET 4.6** solution to **.NET Core 5.02**.  The **.csproj** files were manually migrated [using these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-5.0).  The solution creates DLLs which are plugins for another application; that app loads the DLLs at runtime.  The DLLs created by the solution run fine on my development PC (of course).  When installing these plugins into a pristine copy of the app in Windows Sandbox, one of the DLLs fails with error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=5.0.0.2,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the
file specified.
```

This prevents that DLL from being loaded. A differnt DLL with a reference to **Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility** loads OK but it has no ref to System.Drawing.
The project in which this fails at runtime has System.Drawing installed as a package reference (no packages.config). Again, it compiles and runs correctly on the development PC.

I've tried:

1. uninstalling **System.Drawing** from NuGet, fetching it again from NuGet and reinstalling it in the solution
2. using `Update-Package -reinstall` in the project which resulted with no references needing reinstall, closing and reopening VS2019 ;)
3. used **Publish** on the project but only got a **.nupkg** instead of a DLL and dependencies.

I'm not allowed to post pics (new user) or I would include pics of the Dependencies tree and of the project references in the **.csproj**.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: What if you install [`System.Drawing.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) package? Another thing to consider is if you have different versions of the nuget installed (to your library and to your app).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In the end I think the problem was NuGet and VS 2019.  After deleting the package reference and adding it back a few time, with restarts of VS 2019 in between, everything suddenly worked.  In the failing version only the dll was listed in VS 2019.  Now there are 2 subtrees under System.Drawing.Common.  Interestingly the DLL is .NET 4.6; I'm guessing all the other stuff makes it compatible with net core 5.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following has to be added to the project's .csproj file:

`<PropertyGroup> <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies> </PropertyGroup>`